# Align center and right with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to horizontally center align `group1` and right align `group2` with flex.

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="group1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.group2{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

But everything is just centered, what's the fix?

Comment: This isn't possible with flexbox any more than any other layout...my previous answer applies.

Comment: "What's the fix?" Is that even a question? You could atleast ask for different ways to do it, because flex-box isn't going to work.

Comment: For some alignment options see here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the best what you can do with just **Flexbox**

```css
.holder{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.group1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.group2{
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="group1">
       Center
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Better option is to use **relative/absolute** position with **Flexbox**

```css
.holder{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.group1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
}

.group2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="group1">
       Center
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note the Group1 isn't actually centered.

Comment: Yes because of width of `.group2`, but i think is this is closest you can go with flexbox without using relative/absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks I think this is the closet you'll get with flex.

Answer (score 1):

As flexbox is built on manipulation of margins there is no method of moving one item out of the flow other than using `position:absolute`.

Any other method leaves the center item affected by other elements.

```css
.holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
.group1 {
  background: plum;
}
.group2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="group1">
    Group 1
  </div>
  <div class="group2">
    Group 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Immagine you have a button with a text and a icon and you want the text on the center and the icon on the right. Don't forget to give a width to the button.

With flexbox is really simple to do it.

```css
button {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex: 1;
 width: 400px;
 order: 1;
}

span {
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>
 <span>
  Click me  
 </span>
 <i>></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it using **flex**, **grid** and **position**.

Check out the solution for **flex, grid** as position has already been submitted above

**Flex Solution:**

```css
.holder {
  display: flex;
}
.group1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="group1">...</div>
  <div class="group2">.....</div>
</div>
```

**Grid Solution:**

```css
.holder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0fr;
}
.group1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.group2 {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="group1">...</div>
  <div class="group2">.....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set a height in the `.holder`and the play with `align-self` and `text-align`:

**CSS**

```
.holder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.group2{
    align-self: center;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.group1{
    align-self: center;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/tL2fkLhq/14/)**